# GridView CheckBox

Tags: asp.net

How do I check the checkbox in gridview on the database bit '1' and uncheck on '0' automatically and then submit the checked values into database? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it simply did the job:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active">
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:CheckBox ID="Chk" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("fieldname") %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going

http://www.asp.net/Learn/data-access/tutorial-52-vb.aspx

Comment: But I need the checkbox checked automatically on bit value '1' not on button click.

Answer (score 0):

A templated field may work:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Serial Number" SortExpression="SERIALNUMBER" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# iif(Bind("FIELD")=0,"False","True") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```